# Script fails to delete a row which is hidden by a filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a google spreadsheet with a table where its headers has filters activated in them to be able to hide some rows to see just a group of related data. I've developed an Apps script which iterate over the rows of the table to copy some data and to delete some rows which match a pattern.

The problem is that the script is generating errors and the logs say that the execution time limit is being reached. I've debugged the script patiently and I've found that it fails when it tries to delete a row which is hidden by a filter. Is it normal? Or, is it a bug in Apps script?

I've created a simple test spreadsheet with table like the mentioned above and a simpler Apps script which reproduce the problem. The script copies values from first column to third column and deletes a row if it finds the character 'c' in the second column. I've added three button in the spreadsheet: the first one executes the previous script, the second one deletes the data in the third column and the third one add at the end of the table a row with the character 'c' in the second column. You can access the doc [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LPheTttFN7KWDhqmZ4ZV3q7JPCA3VXCNsFmkREsIybs/edit?usp=sharing).

The code of the test script is the following:

```
function CopyValues() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  let row = 4;

  while(sheet.getRange(row,1).isBlank() == false){
    let character = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    if (character=='c') {
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
    } else {
      let id = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
      sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(id);
      row++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function CopyValues() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  let row = 4;

  // I modified below script.
  const range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 3, 2);
  const values = range.getValues().reduce((ar, [a, b]) => {
    if (b != "c") ar.push([a, b, a]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  range.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  
  // If you want to update the range of the basic filter, please use the following script.
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    var newRange = filter.getRange().offset(0, 0,values.length + 1, values[0].length);
    filter.remove();
    newRange.createFilter();
  }
}
```

- In your script, `getValue` and `setValue` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.
- In this modification, at first, the values are retrieved and filtered the values, and then, put values to the sheet. By this, it reduces the process cost of the script.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: You're a genius, it worked! There is just one problem and it's the fact that filters get reset, so the user has to reconfigure them after the script has been executed.

Comment: The filter criteria can be kept using the filter's methods getColumnFilterCriteria() and setColumnFilterCriteria(). I tried to edit your answer but I couldn't because the edit queue is full.

Comment: @MauroDiamantino Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. So can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: I was able to edit your reply. Once the edition is approved, you'll understand the new question.

Comment: I'm having some strange errors, when the doc has many data, the code fails to process the cells which are hidden by the filters. It seems the bug hasn't been completely solved.

Comment: @MauroDiamantino Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.